# Why is the asymptotic complexity analogy not working?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, mergesort

Recently I come across a question where the asymptotic complexity was asked-

```
T(n, n) where
T(x, c) = Θ(x) for c ≤ 2,
T(c, y) = Θ(y) for c ≤ 2, and
T(x, y) = Θ(x + y) + T(x/2, y/2).
```

And the proposed solution was

```
We may then begin to replace T(x/2, y/2) with the recursive formula containing it:
x + y x + y x + y
T(x, y) = c (x + y) + c(x+y)/4 + c(x+y)/8 ...
This geometric sequence is bounded from above by 2c(x + y), and is obviously
bounded from below by c(x + y). Therefore, T(x, y) is Θ(x + y), and so T(n, n)
is Θ(n).
```

Now what I argue is that for a merge sort type algorithm where

```
 T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n)
```

The resultant time complexity comes out to be nlog(n)
I cannot understand the difference between these two problems ,and as per my analogy of mine the first problem should have been also nlogn.
Please help me where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption of your argument is flawed. T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n) is linear and not nlogn. Merge sort has the recurrence relation T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Theta(n). The factor 2 makes a difference because if you telescope the relation equation you don't get exponentially decreasing terms as you do when the factor is less than 2.

(Note: check out the master theorem, which applies to recurrence relations like this).